# Creating staff users with a checkbox (booleanfield)

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I am making a blog style website, and for the register form, I decided I want to add a checkbox that says 'I'm a staff member' so that if the form is submitted with this box checked said user is registered as a staff member instead of just a normal member. I know this isn't very secure but in my specific case it would work very well.

I know I could do this by creating a different form only for staff members but I really want to do it with the checkbox. **So, the checkbox is there, how can I make it check if it's checked or not to make a staff user?**

ANY kind of help is greatly appreciated.

Here is my code:

*forms.py*

```
class UserRegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(
        label= 'Correo Electrónico',
        required=True,
    )

    username = forms.CharField(max_length=100, required=True, label='Nombre de Usuario')
    
    password1 = forms.CharField(
        label = "Contraseña",
        required=True
    )
    password2 = forms.CharField(
        label = "Confirmar Contraseña",
        required=True
    )
    
    is_teacher = forms.BooleanField(
        label='Soy profesor/a',
        required=True,
    )

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2', 'is_teacher']
```

*views.py*

```
def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserRegisterForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            messages.success(request, f'Tu cuenta se ha creado correctamente, ahora puedes iniciar sesión')
            return redirect('login')

    else:
        form = UserRegisterForm()
    return render(request, 'users/register.html', {'form': form})
```

*models.py*

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(default='default.jpg', upload_to='profile_pics')

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user.username} Profile'

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Profile, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

        img = Image.open(self.image.path)
        
        if img.height > 300 or img.width > 300:
            output_size = (300, 300)
            img.thumbnail(output_size)
            img.save(self.image.path)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve my problem.

I fixed it, by adding a couple things to the code:**

```
def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserRegisterForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save(commit= False)
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            is_teacher = form.cleaned_data.get('is_teacher')
            if is_teacher == True:
                user.is_staff = True
                user.save()
            else:
                user.is_staff = False
                user.save() 
            messages.success(request, f'Tu cuenta se ha creado correctamente, ahora puedes iniciar sesión')
            return redirect('login')

    else:
        form = UserRegisterForm()
    return render(request, 'users/register.html', {'form': form})
```

First I added *'commit = False'* to the *'form.save'* so that it would save it **but it wouldn't send the information to the database right away** (and that's what was messing up the entire thing, it would write everything directly into the database and then it wouldn't change it anymore unless I manually did it through admin), so it holds on to it and then as the code says, if *'is_teacher == True'* (that's the checkbox) it will register that user as a Staff member and after that it saves the form again this time sending the data to the database, and if it was the other way around and *'is_teacher == False'* then it would just do the same but instead of saying *'user.is_staff = True'* it'll say it is false.

I hope I was able to explain myself correctly.